# why is the output is always 0?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, label

Today I started creating a project in Visual Studio 2017 in C# with Windows Forms. The program should calculate the volume of a pyramid with a rectangular base and display the result.

The problem is that if I click the button which should reveal the result, the result is 0.

Heres the important code:

```
// stores height h, side1 a, side2 b
double a, b, h;

//Reads out b from a textbox
private void txbB_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string parseB = txbB.Text;
    b = double.Parse(parseB);
}

//Reads out a from a textbox
private void txbA_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string parseA = txbA.Text;
    a = double.Parse(parseA);
}

//Reads out h from a textbox
private void txbH_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string parseH = txbH.Text;
    h = double.Parse(parseH);
}

//button which calculates the volume of the pyramid 
//when clicked and prints it to the label "LblErgebnis"
private void Cmdrechnen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double Total = 1/3 * h * a * b;
    string Result = Total.ToString();
    LblErgebnis.Text = Result;
}
```

Can someone tell me why the result is always 0?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I've had that since I reached the gold badge some months ago, so I cannot tell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the line `double Total = 1/3 * h * a * b;`, the `1/3` is integer division, resulting in 0. Change that to `1.0 / 3.0`.